# How can I connect my PC connected to WiFi on wlan0 to my oscilloscope on eth0?

Tags: networking, wireless, server, dhcp

Here is how I set up my network configuration on both devices

For Linux comp:

```
wlan0: WiFi Link set to DHCP
eth0: Static IP: 192.168.1.254
      Netmask: 255.255.255.0
      Default Gateway IP and Primary DNS are set blank
```

For my scope that is wired directly to `eth0`:

```
Instrument IP Address: 192.168.1.1
Gateway IP Address: 192.168.1.254
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Http Port:80
Domain Name and DNS IP Address are both left blank
```

I tried pinging the instrument IP address from my Ubuntu machine and testing the connection on the scope which both failed to show a connection. I'm pretty new to this stuff so any insight would help.

**Update:**
For some reason the `setup` tool I was using from the terminal wasn't actually saving my configuration so I just changed it manually from the terminal using `sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.254`. Now I can ping 192.168.1.254 and transmit/receive packets but when I try to ping the instrument IP address, I get:

```
From 192.168.1.254 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable"
```

and am not sure how to proceed.

Here is the output of `ifconfig`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:E8:F2:46:6F  
          inet addr:192.168.1.254  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
          Interrupt:22 Memory:f6ae0000-f6b00000 
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:941 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:941 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:72328 (70.6 KiB)  TX bytes:72328 (70.6 KiB)
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:6A:6E:45:E8  
          inet addr:131.225.175.229  Bcast:131.225.175.255 Mask:255.255.248.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::221:6aff:fe6e:45e8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:234066 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:65309 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:93901249 (89.5 MiB)  TX bytes:9874935 (9.4 MiB)
```

Comment: So the scope has an ethernet plug?

Comment: try this my freind still new but i can help
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing

Comment: @Tim Yes, my scope has an ethernet plug

Comment: Could you please post the output to `ifconfig` into your question?  You need two different IP address schemes and 254 is the default gateway on the oscilloscope, so any address **other then 1 or 254** on your PC should just work, *unless your WiFi has 192.168.1.x as well!* (then I need some more info to help you any further)

Comment: P.S. No, you don't need another WiFi card: you've got everything you need!  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby Thanks, I've included the output to ifconfig. So are you saying it should work if I change the eth0 inet addr to something like 192.168.1.2? I was under the impression that since my scope is connecting to my computer which is connected to the wifi the eth0 IP needed to be the gateway for my scope, but I could very well just be misunderstanding this.

Comment: Informed answer coming up!  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your WiFi is using a public addressing scheme, the 192.168.1.0/24 address scheme can be used to connect your PC to the oscilloscope directly.

So the PC's address should be set to 192.168.1.2 and the oscilloscope's to 192.168.1.3.  The "default gateway" (254) is a reserved address by TCP/IP as is the "broadcast address" (255).  For everything you always wanted to know about TCP/IP but were afraid to ask, read [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201633469).

**Extra credit:** If the link lights on the Ethernet ports do not turn on after the cable is inserted on both ends, you *have to* buy an [Ethernet cross cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable) as not all computer's Ethernet ports can connect directly using just any Ethernet cable.

Comment: As you're a reputation 6 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Comment: So should the gateway IP on the scope be the PC's address (eth0) or should it just be blank?

Comment: Definitely blank!  ;-)  (You don't want this oscilloscope to be available to all machines on your LAN do you???)

Comment: I see. After making the changes I try pinging the scopes IP but I get destination host unreachable. There's an option on the scope to "test connection" but it just returns No response, and when I try entering the scopes IP into my browser which I think should bring me to a site, I just get an unable to connect page. Any suggestions?

Comment: OK, the config of the PC should be: 192.168.1.2 NM 255.255.255.0 and the scope should be 192.168.1.3 NM 255.255.255.0 no gateways anywhere and they should be able to reach each other with a broadcast.  The link lights on the Eth ports are on, aren't they? (also read the answer again: edited)
If that doesn't help, give me the full config of the Ethernet port on the PC.

Comment: Going to sleep! To be continued...

Comment: The ethernet cable was a problem. After switching to a crossover cable I was able to connect. Thanks much!!!